# How to backup data in Google analytics?

Tags: ionic-framework, google-analytics, analytics, google-analytics-api

I am using google analytics in my project (ionic). I am tracking user selections in each page and the final recommendations and those are tracked and sent to google analytics. Those data is getting tracked properly. But now I want to backup those data in the https://analytics.google.com/ dashboard. I already created a backup view (admin > view > view settings > copy view). But already tracked data (events, event labels) are not getting copied. So I need to know a way to get a backup with existing tracked data.

Answer (score 0):

You cannot create a backup view by copying it from another.

Views start populating from the moment they are created and historical data will not be displayed. For this reason, at least 2 views are usually created initially so that you always have a backup view.